# How to add ghosted text to Drupal webform text area?

Tags: php, drupal, textarea, drupal-webform

I would like to know, does anyone know how to add ghosted (light gray) text to a Drupal webform text area to give a description?  The ghosted text should disappear once the user enters something into the text area.

Comment: Are your programming the field yourself? Of do you simply want to create a form in drupal and have the option in the fields module? This module can help you if you are programming it yourself: http://drupal.org/project/placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple no need to install any module, use javascript for place holder

paste this code in head section in page.tpl

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function placeholder()
{
var input = document.getElementById ("edit-message");
input.placeholder = "Add Your Text Here";   

}
</script>
```

Replace "edit-message" with your text area id(use fire bug)

Add this  **onload="javascript:placeholder();"** in body tag

```
<body onload="javascript:placeholder();"  class="<?php print $body_classes; ?>">
```

Simplest method to use place holder, hope it helps!

Comment: It's [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event#HTML_attribute) to avoid using event handlers in HTML, but rather attach the event to the element. Also, why use JS to do this with all this code when all you need is a simple attribute added to the textarea tag? What's the point of the placeholder attribute if you end up using JS anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're looking for is resolved by the HTML5 'placeholder' attribute, implemented for input fields in modern browsers: Firefox 4+, Opera 11+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+ ... and only in IE10+ :(

So IMHO you have 2 ways to implement the 'placeholder functionality' in input fields:

1) The quick & dirty way: using Javascript event handlers. In this way you can support old and modern browsers at the same time, if JS is enabled.

2) The right & up-and-coming solution: using the HTML5 'placeholder' attribute.

As you may guess, 2nd approach is harder to implement, because the placeholder attribute is not natively supported in Drupal 7 forms. To get Drupal to render  fields with the placeholder="hint..." attribute:

a) If you use Webform Module v.7.x-3.x or 7.x-4.x for building your forms, just apply to it the patch published in this thread: http://drupal.org/node/1305826, and/or...

b) Pre-process the forms markup in your theme's template.php file, as described in: http://nathanbuskirk.com/drupal7-placeholder-text-and-html5-forms

In both cases, support of IE6-9 and other old browsers will need you to additionally use some pollyfill JS library, like Placeholder.js ( https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js ) or JQuery' Simple-Placeholder.js ( https://github.com/marcgg/Simple-Placeholder )

Hope it helps.